# Suppress Prompt for Confirmation to Import CRM Organization

Tags: powershell, crm, confirm, suppress

I am trying to Import CRM Organization using PowerShell. Execution of the script below, prompts for confirmation. I need to suppress this prompt, and for that so far I've added `-confirm false`, `-confirm:$false`, `-confirm $false`, `echo 'Y'` & `$ConfirmPreference='None'`, but the prompt persists. Any Suggestions?

```
[ScriptBlock] $global:ImportOrg = {
    param ()
    $sqlSnapin = Get-PSSnapin | where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell"}
    if($sqlSnapin -eq $null)
    {
         Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell
    }
    $ConfirmPreference="None"
    $ConfirmPreference
    $Password1 = ConvertTo-SecureString "XXXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force
    $Creds1 = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "XXXX\YYYYYY", $Password1
    Import-CrmOrganization -SqlServerName "localhost\XXXXX" -DatabaseName "XXXXXXX"  -SrsUrl "http://XXX/YYYY/ZZZZ" -Credential $Creds1  -DisplayName "XYZ" -Name "XYZ" 
        -UserMappingMethod "ByAccount" -Confirm $false -Verbose -DwsServerUrl "https://XXX/YYY/deployment.svc" -diag  
    echo "Y"
}

$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'XXXXXX' -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'XXXX\YYYYYY', $Password
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'VVVVVVV' -Credential $Creds
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $ImportOrg
```

Comment: `-Confirm:$false` (notice the `:` between confirm and $false) is the correct way

Comment: I have already tried that Mathias. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved. I was trying to set "None" for $ConfirmPreference and $false for -Confirm, this messed up things. After going through the documentation on 'Get-Help about_Preference_Variables' realized setting $ConfirmPreference="None" suffices, there is no need to add -confirm:$false and it worked! Thanks.